# Apply regression across multiple columns using columns from different dataframe as independent variables

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am looking to conduct regressions across a subset of columns in Data1 using "x" variables from both Data1 and "x" variables from Data2 that correspond to columns in Data1.  I then want extract the p values.  Basically, I want I want the regressions to “loop” like:

Data1$Y1~ Data1$X1 + Data1$X2+ Data1$X3_Y1

Data1$Y2~ Data1$X1 + Data1$X2+ Data2$X3_Y2

Data1$Y3~ Data1$X1 + Data1$X2+ Data2$X3_Y3

Data1$Y4~ Data1$X1 + Data1$X2+ Data2$X3_Y4

Here is what I have come up with:

```
X1 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
X2 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
Y1 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 7, sd = 4)
Y2 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 5, sd = 6)
Y3 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 9, sd = 7)
Y4 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 8, sd = 6)
X3_Y1<- rnorm(n=50, mean = 12, sd = 2)
X3_Y2<- rnorm(n=50, mean = 9, sd = 1)
X3_Y3<- rnorm(n=50, mean = 6, sd = 2)
X3_Y4<- rnorm(n=50, mean = 5, sd = 3)
Data1 <- data.frame(X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4)
Data2 <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3_Y1, X3_Y2, X3_Y3, X3_Y4)

Data1_Y<-colnames(Data1[,3:6])
Data2_XY<-colnames(Data2[,3:6])

 for (y in Data1_Y) {
   for (xy in Data2_XY) {

     MergedX<-cbind(Data1[,c(1:2)],Data2[, xy]) 

         test <- lm(y~MergedX)

     out<-data.frame ("p.value"=test$p.value)

 }}
```

This is not working, however.  I am hoping that there is a way to do this, perhaps using lapply?

NOTE:  The Y1, Y2, etc. are just representative labels.  In the real dataset, Y1, Y2, etc. are specific bacteria names.

Comment: `lapply(X = 1:4, FUN = function(ind) lm(Data1[[paste("Y", ind, sep = "")]]~ Data1$X1 + Data1$X2 + Data2[[paste("X3_Y", ind, sep = "")]]))` 4 models in a list. It is trivial to extract any fit statistics from this list using `lapply/sapply`.

Comment: The issue is that in my dataset, the variables aren't labeled X1, X2, etc.  Instead, they are bacteria names.  I just simplified the names for the example data I provided.  Therefore, I don't think the code you provided will work.  I will go ahead and clarify this in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Same concept, just feed a list of names `Y1...Y4` and `X3_Y1...X3_Y4` into `mapply`. `mapply(function(name1, name2) lm(data1[[name1]]~data1$fixedname + data1$fixedname2 + data2[[name2]]), name1 = c('blah', 'blah', ...'blah'), name2 = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to put you data in a single data frame

```
dd = cbind( Data1, Data2)
```

Then loop over the number of `X` coefficients, building each model in turn,

```
for(i in 1:4) {
  model = paste0("Y", i, "~ X1 + X2 + X3_Y", i)
  m = lm(model, data=dd)
}
```

You could of course remove the `for` loop and use `lapply`. But I won't bother, as it doesn't bring you that much benefit.

---

In your question, you wanted to extract a p-value, but it wasn't which one (and your code didn't work). You can extract the p-values for each variable using

```
summary(m)[[4]][,4]
```

inside the loop.